# how to generate gaussian pseudo random numbers in c for a given mean and variance?

Tags: c, random, numbers, gaussian

I  have a code here which generates random numbers having a mean 0f 1 and std deviation of 0.5. but how do i modify this code so that i can denerate gaussian random numbers of any given mean and variance?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

double drand()   /* uniform distribution, (0..1] */
{
  return (rand()+1.0)/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}

double random_normal() 
 /* normal distribution, centered on 0, std dev 1 */
{
  return sqrt(-2*log(drand())) * cos(2*M_PI*drand());
}

int main()
{

  int i;
  double rands[1000];
  for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
  rands[i] = 1.0 + 0.5*random_normal();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 10):

> I have a code here which generates random numbers having a mean 0f 1
>   and std deviation of 0.5. but how do i modify this code so that i can
>   denerate gaussian random numbers of any given mean and variance?

If `x` is a random variable from a Gaussian distribution with mean `μ` and standard deviation `σ`, then `αx+β` will have mean `αμ+β` and standard deviation `|α|σ`.

In fact, the code you posted already does this transformation.  It starts with a random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation 1 (obtained from the function `random_normal`, which implements the [Box–Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)), and then transforms it to a random variable with mean 1 and standard deviation 0.5 (in the `rands` array) via multiplication and addition:

```
double random_normal();  /* normal distribution, centered on 0, std dev 1 */

rands[i] = 1.0 + 0.5*random_normal();
```

Comment: A typo: `αx+β` has mean `αμ+β`, not `μ+β`, and the standard deviation is better expressed as `|α|σ` to take into account the possibility that `α` is negative: standard deviation cannot be a negative number.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this- all of which basically involve transforming/mapping your uniformly distributed values to a normal/gaussian distribution.  A [Ziggurat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) transformation is probably your best bet.

One thing to keep in mind- the quality of your end distribution is only as good as your RNG, so be sure to use a quality random number generator (e.g.- Mersenne twister) if the quality of the generated values is important.