# iOS Gaussian distribution of random numbers

Tags: ios, random, distribution, gaussian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a random Gaussian double in Objective-C/C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779843/generating-a-random-gaussian-double-in-objective-c-c)

Is there any way of getting a random number not from a uniform distribution, but from a Gaussian (Normal, Bell Curve) distribution in iOS? All the random number generators I have found are basically uniform and I want to make the numbers cluster around a certain point. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a random Gaussian double in Objective-C/C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779843/generating-a-random-gaussian-double-in-objective-c-c) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034930/how-to-generate-gaussian-pseudo-random-numbers-in-c-for-a-given-mean-and-varianc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a uniform distribution generator and apply the [Box-Muller Transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html):

```
double u1 = (double)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX; // uniform distribution
double u2 = (double)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX; // uniform distribution
double f1 = sqrt(-2 * log(u1));
double f2 = 2 * M_PI * u2;
double g1 = f1 * cos(f2); // gaussian distribution
double g2 = f1 * sin(f2); // gaussian distribution
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about this transform. Many thanks!

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) for the “polar” version of this, which avoids the trig functions but may require more calls to the uniform generator.

Comment: Polar form for Objective-C is also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8779877/1431728).

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks, but isn't `log( u1 )` `-infinite` when `arc4random` returns `0` ?

Comment: The probability of generating ±∞ is about 1/(2^32 - 1) ≈ 2.32831*10^-10. (I say “about” because when `f1` is -∞, there is a 1/UINT32_MAX probability that `g2` is NaN.) The min/max finite values for `g1` and `g2` are sqrt(2*log(1/UINT32_MAX)) ≈ ±6.66044. The total probability outside of those finite extrema is erfc(sqrt(log(2^32 - 1))) ≈ 2.73015*10^-11. So there is a larger than proper probability of generating ±∞.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is to add several numbers from a uniform distribution together. Many dice based games use this approach to generate roughly normal distributions of results.

[image: Distribution of rolling 3 6 sided dice]

via [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Roll_of_3d6.svg)

If you can be more specific about what distribution you want there may be more precise solutions but combining several rolls is an easy and fairly flexible solution.