# random value generator with normal distribution for objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, normal-distribution

I would like to generate numbers into an array that has normal distribution. Is there any function in objective-c or c that can help to get the result easily without any math?

Comment: You are true, but I thought there is some methods that can help this achieve a lot easier

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948293/ios-gaussian-distribution-of-random-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the the Box-Muller-Transformation:

1.) you need two uniform distributed random numbers u and v as doubles in the interval (0,1]   (0 needs to be excluded):

```
double u =(double)(random() %100000 + 1)/100000; //for precision
double v =(double)(random() %100000 + 1)/100000; //for precision
```

2.) calculate the uniform distributed value with average of 0 and the standard deviation sigma of 1:

```
double x = sqrt(-2*log(u))*cos(2*pi*v);   //or sin(2*pi*v)
```

3.) if needed add sigma and average for your target distribution like this:

```
double y = x * sigmaValue + averageValue;
```

4.) put it in an array

```
[randomNumberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:y]]
```

There is no function `norminv` for objc. So, math is needed here.

Edit: I like using `random()` to be able to seed the random value generator

Comment: This is really a great solution, but one questions: will this order the numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't. And (for large arrays) please consider to check and exclude u and v for the value 0 and 1. Otherwise the log-function won't work.

Comment: What is wrong with sorting it with `[randomNumberArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` afterwards?

Comment: @JFS, is it suppose to have negative numbers?

Comment: @dwbrito, it will generate negative numbers as well. If you follow the equations until step 2 it will generate normal distributed values with the average of zero (example: http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATS2/normal67.gif). So, there will be positive and negative values.

Comment: @JFS, I thought it was only negative. I ended up using the Ziggurat algorithm

Comment: @dwbrito, no it is not just generating negative values. The Ziggurat algorithm is actually similar but not as easy to implement than the Box-Muller transformation.

Answer (score 2):

*Let me preface this by saying, please, correct me if I'm wrong!*

It's my understanding that the Box-Muller Transformation relies on the source numbers being them selves uniformly distributed, thus using random() or rand() as the source data-set for Box-Muller will ***NOT*** necessarily produce a uniform distribution.

It is instead intended to take a generic set of uniformly distributed random numbers, and produce independent pairs of random numbers uniformly distributed in a 2D coordinate system.

[Wikipedia: Box-Muller Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

---

There is however another way:

On most Unix systems (*and thus Objective C on iOS or OSX*) using the **rand48** library of functions:

[Reference: drand](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/drand48.html)

```
double drand48(void);
void srand48(long int seedval);
```

srand48() seeds the generator, and drand48() produces random numbers uniformly distributed over the interval [0.0 - 1.0]

Comment: thank you for the interesting discussion. As long as there are two independent uniform distributed values in the interval of (0,1] the Box-Muller approach should generate normal distributed values. But I agree that the source quality for random number generator has an effect on the results. I don't like the quality of `random()` but I need to create the same sequence with normal distributed numbers. That's why I can't use arc4random() or other better approaches. How would I implement these Unix function in iOS?

Comment: srand48() and drand48() functions are available in iOS as @Adam said.